# Not responding process in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

How to identify not responding process in windows xp by making use of command line or batch script?
Please tell me the command.
I tried using  and it's not returning not responding process. Please suggest me some other command.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, theres no built in tool that can detect processes not responding.   If [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) can't do it, I'm not sure what can.

You're probably better off building a console app in C or C# to do what you want.   See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304991) for more information in C#.